# android:style reference after SDK and ADT plugin update in mid 2011

Tags: android, adt, r.java-file

I see a lot a similar questions *R.java can't compile , No resource found that matches @android:style/*  ***"just after SDK & ADT update"***  leading to existing projects can't compile
The R.java file cannot be compiled. I find out the errors come from referencing

```
<style name="Theme.Wallpaper" parent="android:style/Theme.Wallpaper" >
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
```

What is happening is that some styles, like Theme.Wallpaper are not public. You should not extend from them anymore.

Some suggest to revert to platform_tools_r05
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367&pli=1

If you want to do the correct way 
read Xavier July 28
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367&pli=1

> If you wish to reuse a style that is private, you should copy the
>   content of that style into your own instead of extending it.

Ok so Where do I find the content of the (private) style ? 
Seriously, after an update I don't have time to correct platform mistakes when the project code worked right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Default theme for windows that want to have the user's selected
     wallpaper appear behind them.  -->
<style name="Theme.Wallpaper">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```

Looks like you want to use the above code from the [Android source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) and create your own theme based it.

Comment: Thanks ! I did not want to dig into the android source code but for this one you had to do it.

Comment: As the source is online you can just google for it usually and you come across the github webclient for android source.