# Error while deploying sample code by android, project:android api demos

Tags: android

I am getting following error on deploying one of the sample projects given by android: android api demos for api level 8 :

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.Wallpaper'.
```

at values/styles.xml line 43

```
<style name="Theme.Wallpaper" parent="android:style/Theme.Wallpaper">
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
```

I have been looking for solutions for over a month now. I have tried rebuilding project, dowloading entire source code again and rebuilding and cleaning.
Help

Comment: It is working fine here. Try parent="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper". While typing @android:style/ intellisense should show you the available Themes. + Check the build target of your project

Comment: cant find sdk target in manifest, modified according to an answer, not working then also.

Comment: I am not sure if you have the default proguard options introduced in new versions of the android tools. Advice: update your android tools in your sdk manager, and update your adt plugin. Create a new project and move all your resources to the new project. You will have a file `proguard-project.txt`. Add to it the -dontwarn statement.

Comment: Can you please shed more light on this.

Comment: Well, if you have the proguard-project.txt in your project then forget what am saying. I am assuming you're using the eclipse ADT plugin on a windows pc. Just update the sdk and adt. Create a new project. Copy your sources and resources to the new project. Add the -dontwarn statement to proguard-project.txt. Export.

Comment: I am sorry. My comments were meant for another question. my mistake ): sorry

Answer (score 4):

As Very Well Explain by raychenon.

```
<style name="Theme.Wallpaper" parent="android:style/Theme.Wallpaper" >
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#fff</item>
</style>
```

What is happening is that some styles, like Theme.Wallpaper are not public. You should not extend from them anymore.

Some suggest to revert to platform_tools_r05 [HERE](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367&pli=1)

If you want to do the correct way read Xavier July 28 [HERE](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367&pli=1)

> If you wish to reuse a style that is private, you should copy the
>   content of that style into your own instead of extending it.

**ANSWER**

> Default theme for windows that want to have the user's selected
>         wallpaper appear behind them.

```
<style name="Theme.Wallpaper">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
</style>
```

Looks like you want to use the above code from the [Android source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) and create your own theme based it.

Hope it Will Helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this question posted here and read Xavier's comments on the Google blog..

[style reference after SDK and ADT plugin update in mid 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258408/androidstyle-reference-after-sdk-and-adt-plugin-update-in-mid-2011)

Hope it helps..Keep me posted

Comment: done that it is not working. please check comment above in the question

Answer (score 0):

When you import the Android Samples via "Android projects from existing code", I noticed that the libraries and API number are Android 1.5 and API level 3.

This API Level doesn't support ***android:style/Theme.Wallpaper***.

I fixed it by adjusting the **Project Build Target** to Android 2.2 (API Level 8) in the Project Properties Menu.